# Drools variable cannot be accessed in then clause

Tags: java, drools

I have an Object Class with a couple of fields and methods that I can successfully access in the when clause:

```
public final class ObjectWrapper {

   private Object object;
   private Date approvalDate;
   
   public getObject() {
       return object;
   }
   
   <remaining getters and setters>

}
```

This is similar to the structure of my drools rule:

```
rule "IS_ELIGIBLE"
when
    ObjectWrapper(
                  $object : getObject(),
                  <remaining conditions>
                 )
then
    System.out.println($object);
end
```

IntelliJ complains right away telling me that it cannot resolve the symbol **$object**. The variable only seems to be accessible if I do the following, but the **getObject()** method cannot be accessed from outside the Wrapper context.

```
rule "IS_ELIGIBLE"
when
    $object : getObject(),
    ObjectWrapper(
                  <remaining conditions>
                 )
then
    System.out.println($object);
end
```

What's the proper way of dealing with variables in using the drools framework? Would it be possible to declare the variable outside and then change its value inside the wrapper?

There are other drools files in the project where the above code works, but for that one, the variable is only accessible in the ***then*** clause if it's declared outside the wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ's code formatting is pretty good, but it's also got some known bugs and the publisher isn't particularly interested in fixing it. Just because the code formatter says it's wrong doesn't mean that it actually is (though it's usually right.) Take its recommendations with a grain of salt.

Based on what you've shown, the correct syntax for your rule should be this:

```
rule "IS_ELIGIBLE"
when
    ObjectWrapper( $object: object,
                  <remaining conditions>
                 )
then
    System.out.println($object);
end
```

When you have something like `ObjectWrapper( $o: object )`, Drools will first look for a public variable called `object`, and then look for a method called `getObject` (basically following the bean naming conventions.) Generally the only time you'd invoke a method would be for something that doesn't meet the naming conventions ... eg if you have a `doFoo()` that returns a boolean that you want to assign the results of.

Your rule as shown (`ObjectWrapper( $object: getObject() )`) also works fine. The code formatter is just confused. The version I provide is syntactically equivalent, and is more "Drools-like", but there's nothing wrong with what you've shown as your attempt.